# electron-react-boilerplate splash screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an electron app that was instantiated using the `electron-react-boilerplate`. I would like to add a splash screen. Namely, I have the following piece of code:

```js
splash = new BrowserWindow({
        icon: getAssetPath("icon.png"),
        transparent: true,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        frame: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 800,
    });

splash.loadURL(resolveHtmlPath("splash.html"));
```

Where `resolveHtmlPath` is defined by the following code:

```js
let resolveHtmlPath: (htmlFileName: string) => string;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 1212;
    resolveHtmlPath = (htmlFileName: string) => {
        const htmlUrl = new URL(`http://localhost:${port}`);
        htmlUrl.pathname = htmlFileName;
        return htmlUrl.href;
    };
} else {
    resolveHtmlPath = (htmlFileName: string) => {
        const myurl = url.format({
            pathname: path.resolve(__dirname, "../renderer/", htmlFileName),
            protocol: "file:",
            slashes: true,
        });
        return myurl;
    };
}
```

I know that `electron-react-boilerplate` builds the react app during packaging and creates an html `index.html` file that is served to the renderer process. Now, I would like to create something similar but for a splash page called `splash.html`

Comment: And your problem is? What have you tried, what doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using electron-builder, you can make this like me.

In `package.json` file, i add `extra-ressources` like this:

```json
  "build": {
    "productName": "exemple",
    ... 
    "extraResources": [
      "./assets/**",
      "./splash/**",
    ]
  },
...
```

All folders in `extra-ressources`, are available in `ressources` folder when your application is packaged. [docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/contents.html#extraresources)

In the `main.ts`, i am using the tenary operator to verify if my application is packaged and after that, i am getting the path of my splash screen.

```
const splash = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1024,
    height: 728,
    movable: true,
    center: true,
    icon: getAssetPath('icon.png'),
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
  });

  const splashScreenSrc = app.isPackaged
    ? path.join(process.resourcesPath, 'splash', 'splash.html')
    : path.join(__dirname, '../../splash', 'splash.html');

  splash.loadFile(splashScreenSrc);
```